# Substantive mit zwei Präpositionen: „Angst vor/um“

Tags: word-usage, preposition, noun, slang

Manchmal ändert die Präposition die Bedeutung des Substantivs  wie z. B :

> 1. – Ich habe Angst um dich.
> 2. – Ich habe Angst vor dir.

Ich weiß, dass einige Substantive mit zwei Präpositionen zusammen in einem Satz vorkommen können, beispielsweise die Erhöhung *um + auf*, aber meine Frage geht um das Substantiv *Angst*. Kann man die zwei Präpositionen gleichzeitig in einem Satz verwenden? Kann ich sagen

> Ich habe Angst um dich vor ihm.

oder

> Ich habe Angst um dich davor, dass … etc.

Falls ja , verwendet man diese Struktur (ich meine den Satz) im Alltag? Es hört sich bisschen komisch an.

Comment: Ja, das hört sich sehr komisch an.

Comment: _Ich habe Angst um dich **und** vor ihm_ kinda works, but it borders on being a play on words.

Comment: @Crissov: But that means something different than what seems to have been the intention, doesn't it?

Comment: Uh, then perhaps _Ich habe Angst um dich **wegen** ihm_ or rather _Ich habe **seinetwegen** Angst um dich_.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

„Ich habe Angst vor Jerome“ bedeutet, daß ich Angst um *meine eigene Sicherheit* habe. „Ich habe Angst um Danielle“ bedeutet, daß ich Angst *um Danielles Sicherheit* habe. Die beiden Bedeutungen schließen sich also gegenseitig aus, und deshalb wäre ein Satz, der beide Konstruktionen verwendet, schwer oder gar nicht zu verstehen.

Es handelt sich also nicht um einen syntaktischen Ausschluß – es gibt durchaus Wörter, die mit mehreren Präpositionen idiomatisch zusammenstehen. Das funktioniert sogar mit *derselben* Präposition: Man kann *im Sommer* verreisen oder *im Zug* oder auch beides zugleich, denn diese Bedeutungsanteile sind voneinander unabhängig.

Answer (score 2):

Nein, das ist nicht möglich. Die beiden Bedeutungen können nicht in dieser Weise kombiniert werden.

Um den Grund für die Angst näher zu benennen, kann man zahlreiche andere Formulierungen wählen, zum Beispiel

> Ich habe Angst um dich. Ich fürchte, dass er sich an dir rächen will.

Comment: nach welcher grammatikregel genau ist der satz "Ich habe Angst um dich und vor ihm." falsch?

Comment: @anion: Um den Satz geht es nicht.

Comment: @anion Dieser Satz ist nicht falsch (und ich erinnere mich vage, dass wir vor nicht allzu langer Zeit eine frage zu einer ähnlichen Formulierung hatten, kann sie aber derzeit nicht finden). Meine Antwort bezog sich nur auf die Formulierung in der Frage, nicht auf Crissovs Kommentar.

Comment: @Hulk
Ich erinnere mich auch an eine ähnliche Frage, darum war ich um so mehr verwundert ;-)

Comment: Der Satz ist einfach unklar.